# Jquery show/ hide only works for first item

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

**HTML**

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <label>Leave Type</label>
                            @Html.DropDownList("LeaveType", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <br />
                            <label>Start Date</label>
                            @Html.TextBox("datetime.now", String.Format("{0:d}", "Start date"), new { id="startDate", @class = "datepicker", type = "text" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <br />
                            <label>End Date</label>
                            @Html.TextBox("01-01-2015", String.Format("{0:d}", "End date"), new { id = "endDate", @class = "datepicker", type = "text" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#LeaveType').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "1") {
                $('#endDate').show();
                $('#startDate').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#startDate').hide();
                $('#endDate').hude();
            }
        })
```

I want to hide certain items when the user selects a specific value from the Leave Type dropdownlist. But its only working for the first value. I want to hide the label as well so I tried putting the `id` in the `div class` but it didn't work that way. I tried using `name` as well, following other people's solution on SOF but I had no luck too. Please help!

Comment: id should be unique. use class instead of it..

Comment: Try `$('#endDate').closest('.form-group').show();` and `$('#startDate').closest('.form-group').show();` and hide the entire div.. also please note that its `.hide` not `.hude`, if at all you've missed for `#endDate`..

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
$('#endDate').hide();
```

instead of

```
$('#endDate').hude();
```